# What are benefits of @Immutable on a data class?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

Looking at the [documentation of Immutable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/Immutable), there's a code example:

```
@Immutable
data class Person(val name: String, val phoneNumber: String)

@Composable
fun PersonView(person: Person) {
    Column {
        Row {
            Text("Name: ")
            Text(person.name)
        }
        Row {
            Text("Phone: ")
            Text(person.phoneNumber)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun PeopleView(people: List<Person>) {
    Column {
        for (person in people) {
            PersonView(person)
        }
    }
}
```

and a caption:

> Marking Person immutable allows calls the PersonView Composable function to be skipped if it is the same person as it was during the last composition.

My question is:

If recomposition occurs only when arguments of `@Composable` function change and data classes like `Person` in the code above (i.e. containing only primitive vals) cannot be changed without creating a new instance, then what's the optimization here?
When would the calls to the PersonView Composable function be skipped compared to the same code but *without* the `@Immutable` annotation? Is it somehow related to the mutable/unstable argument `people: List<Person>` of `PeopleView`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the `Person` class is declared in the same module, there is no difference (with or without the `@Immutable`), because Compose compiler will automatically infer that the Composable is skippable. You can check it by generating Compose compiler reports.

However, when the `Person` comes from another module in a multimodule app (or from external library) and does not have the `@Immutable` annotation, then the Composable will not be skippable (cannot be inferred). There is an exception to the rule: if Compose compiler is enabled on the other module the stability is inferred anyway.

> Is it somehow related to the mutable/unstable argument people: List of PeopleView?

Yes, the concept is the same, here the `List` interface does not guarantee immutability of the underlaying list (it may be `MutableList`), so by default `List` is not skippable and causes recomposition every state update.

Good read: [compose-api-guidelines](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main/compose/docs/compose-api-guidelines.md)